# How to fix faulty header row in table

Tags: excel

I've experienced an intermittent issue for a number of years with table headers (seemingly) randomly losing the ability to select columns with the black down arrow that should appear; the arrow simply stops appearing.

Searching online has only yielded a single thread on the answers.microsoft website, but the thread author mentioned VBA and the microsoft team jumped on that probably being the cause, then nobody ever came back with a solution. This issue has definitely occured for me in xlsx format spreadsheets though, before I was using any code.

The issue isn't massive, but it makes certain actions much slower, and the only solution I've found to date is to convert the table back to a range, then back to a table. Obviously this isn't ideal as it means having to fix every formula that refers to this table.

I'm wondering whether anyone else has ever suffered from/experienced this issue, what causes it (so I can avoid it happening), and whether there is a solution to fix it once it does happen.

In case anyone is wondering, I'm currently using Excel 365, but this definitely occurred before we upgraded (I think we were using 10 or 13). Other tables within the same workbook have the correct arrow function, and there are no other issues that I can find.

Comment: A quick update to this. I was working on worksheet and had this issue occur between two saved versions. I'm pretty sure that the only changes I had made were to do with formulae in the table, but I realised that I had also be toggling between protecting and unprotecting the worksheet. As protecting the worksheet removes certain features, perhaps this is a bug where the protect function accidentally toggles something off that it shouldn't. This might explain why the issue remains even when making a new table in the same worksheet, but not on a new worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

You're not alone.  I was plagued by this issue for a week last year and I had the same problem finding good accurate information.

If I'm not mistaken, I had the same table behaving the same way in two different computers, one was office 2010, the other was 365 Pro Plus.

I wish I could tell you the exact step that solved it, but I cannot; because I went thermonuclear faster than a polar bear sweats in sauna.

I exported my VbA project and saved every sheet as a csv.  Then opened a fresh workbook and brought everything back in.

Do you have to do that? Probably not.  But how much is your sanity worth?

Every now and then I get bent out of shape because I think a table started acting up on the left hand side, where I can select the worksheet row but not the most listrow....  But it's mostly nerves and paranoia, the problem has not returned.

Comment: Thanks for confirming someone else has had this issue over multiple Office versions. I ended up copying the data over to a different worksheet and making a new table out of it. I did try converting the existing table to a range and then back to a table, but this didn't work, meaning it's potentially an issue with the worksheet?

Comment: Yes, I believe this is worksheet related but I have nothing but speculation to prove it.